# swap various size words in multiple lines with vim

Tags: vim, vi

I've got some code that does manual encoding/decoding, which I need to extend. The encoding looks like:

```cpp
map["some_key"] = some_struct.member;
map["some_other_key"] = some_other_struct.member;
```

to decode I need to swap the parts of the text around '=' (ex. have some_struct.member = map["some_key"]). Needless to say it's a lot of lines I have to edit, so I wanted to automate this somehow. I'm using vim, but the best I could come up with was to pad the "] part to "_____] to have '=' align and then do the Ctrl+V, then d, then ... you know. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro:

```
" start macro, saving in q register
qq
" (edit one line to do what you want)
" end recording
q
" visually select other lines, hit :, vim starts command line with '<,'>
:'<,'>norm @q
```

My q register to edit your lines:

```
^"xd/ =
xxx$i = jk"xp
```

I have jk mapped to esc, you'll probably need something else there.

Comment: Vimgolf: `:%norm 2Wdt;^vEp;p`. Replace `%` range with a visual one as needed

Comment: Vimgolf: `:%norm $dB^vEp$P` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a macro, too, recorded or not:

```
:%norm! di"t;vBpF"P
:%norm! $dBF"vi"p$P
```